# Issue with arudino car bot, the servo motor moves randomly also it becomes hot pretty quickly

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, servo

I am an ABSOLUTE BEGINNER

I am trying to create an Arduino avoiding obstacle car.
I am using Arduino uno +shield (sensor sheild v5.0) the problem is that when I upload the colde, the servo moves randomly(it doesn't rotate to the right) and becomes hot quickly, it is an SG90 with 5v.
I have already checked several times and the hardware seems all right.

I have tried to change the angle of the servo, checked the pins several times-
uploaded the code many times
I have also used serial.prints.
researched on the internet.

````
#include <NewPing.h>        //Ultrasonic sensor function library. You must install this library

//our L298N control pins
const int LeftMotorForward = 5;
const int LeftMotorBackward = 4;
const int RightMotorForward = 1;
const int RightMotorBackward = 0;

//sensor pins
#define trig_pin A1 //analog input 1
#define echo_pin A2 //analog input 2

#define maximum_distance 200
boolean goesForward = false;
int distance = 100;

NewPing sonar(trig_pin, echo_pin, maximum_distance); //sensor function
Servo servo_motor; //our servo name


void setup(){

  pinMode(RightMotorForward, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LeftMotorForward, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LeftMotorBackward, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RightMotorBackward, OUTPUT);

  servo_motor.attach(11); //our servo pin

  servo_motor.write(90);
  delay(2000);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
}

void loop(){

  int distanceRight = 0;
  int distanceLeft = 0;
  delay(50);

  if (distance <= 20){
    moveStop();
    delay(300);
    moveBackward();
    delay(400);
    moveStop();
    delay(300);
    distanceRight = lookRight();
    delay(300);
    distanceLeft = lookLeft();
    delay(300);

    if (distance >= distanceLeft){
      turnRight();
      moveStop();
    }
    else{
      turnLeft();
      moveStop();
    }
  }
  else{
    moveForward(); 
  }
    distance = readPing();
}

int lookRight(){  
  servo_motor.write(10);
  delay(500);
  int distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  servo_motor.write(90);
  return distance;
}

int lookLeft(){
  servo_motor.write(170);
  delay(500);
  int distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  servo_motor.write(90);
  return distance;
  delay(100);
}

int readPing(){
  delay(70);
  int cm = sonar.ping_cm();
  if (cm==0){
    cm=250;
  }
  return cm;
}

void moveStop(){

  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, LOW);
}

void moveForward(){

  if(!goesForward){

    goesForward=true;

    digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, LOW); 
  }
}

void moveBackward(){

  goesForward=false;

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, LOW);

}

void turnRight(){

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, LOW);

  delay(500);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, LOW);



}

void turnLeft(){

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, LOW);

  delay(500);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorForward, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorForward, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(LeftMotorBackward, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RightMotorBackward, LOW);
}```

Expected to the servo to rotate 90 degrees, but right now the servo is moving randomly-
````

Comment: You may have better luck over on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sometime you just get a bad part...its always nice to have two.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in electronics but if the motor becomes hotter (in a abnormal way), the source might giving higher output (Volts/Amps) that the input of the motor cannot handle (max Volts/Amps). Try to test the source if it gives more than the max current and voltage of the motor.